# call coupon press advanced search widget anywhere in theme?

Tags: widgets, search

I am working on a parent child [Coupon Press](http://couponpress.com/) Wordpress Website. I am able to call it's New  Advanced Search Widget in sidebar but I want to call it anywhere in the website like I have created a page (Advanced Search) and I want to call that widget on this page rather than in sidebar.

I searched on internet and found [`the_widget`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widget) but it's not working and also I don't know the actual name of "New Advanced Search" Widget.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by "the actual name". If you need the class name, look in the source of the theme for `extends WP_Widget`. Other widget information is stored in the `$wpdb->options` table under keys starting with `widget_`. Once you find that you can use `get_option( 'widget_name' );` to get information about active widgets, including the "instance" of the widget which you have to know in order to use `the_widget`.

This may or may not be a duplicate question, but the answer certainly applies: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/97262/21376